# How can I merge two objects of different lengths based on the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash, ecmascript-5

I have two arrays of objects, both arrays containing key,value pair. my objective is to assign key value, from one array to the second array if the string value of one key `name` matches the string value of another key `_id`.

I have tried combining the two arrays into one array and just have one array with the objects but I am still not sure how i can assign key and value to the other objects based on matching value of the key `_id` and `name`. I know how to with the same key but how do we do it based on a different key and same value?
 It might be bad design and practice but that's how the data is coming back. Is it doable? I have tried using lodash, spread operation, map with no success.

```
arr1 = [
{"_id": "electronics", "number": 35 },
{"_id": "house Appliances", "number": 5 },
{"_id": "nothing", "number":0}
]

arr2 = [
{"name": "electronics", "purpose": "entertainment", "price": 100},
{"name": "house Appliances", "purpose": "general", "price": 200},
{"name": "watches", "purpose": "time", "price": 30} ]

combinedArrObj = [
{"name": "electronics", "number": 35, "purpose": "entertainment", "price": 100},
{"name": "house Appliances", "purpose": "general", "price": 200, "number": 5}, 
{"name": "watches", "purpose": "time", "price": 30}
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you do not need to overcomplicate this if you only going to have **one** `key value` pair in `array1`. Simply convert to a map and then [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through `array2` and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create the merge without lodash etc.

```js
const arr1 = [{"_id": "electronics", "number": 35 }, {"_id": "house Appliances", "number": 5 }]
const arr2 = [{"name": "electronics", "purpose": "entertainment", "price": 100},{"name": "house Appliances", "purpose": "general", "price": 200},{"name": "watches", "purpose": "time", "price": 30}]

let map = arr1.reduce((acc, {_id, number}) => (acc[_id] = number, acc), {})

let result = arr2.map(({name, ...rest}) => 
  Object.assign({ name }, rest, map[name] ? { number: map[name] } : {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and find

- First check if any matching `_id` is present in `arr1` for corresponding name
- if it's present we merge the value from of that element in final output
- Else just keep the `inp` only in output

```js
let arr1 = [{"_id": "electronics", "number": 35 },"_id": "house Appliances", "number": 5 }]

let arr2 = [{"name": "electronics", "purpose": "entertainment", "price": 100},{"name": "house Appliances", "purpose": "general", "price": 200},{"name": "watches", "purpose": "time", "price": 30} ]

let final = arr2.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let found = arr1.find(({_id})=>_id===inp.name)
  let name = inp.name
  op[name] = op[name] || {}
  if(found){
    let {_id, ...rest} = found
    op[name] = {...op[name], ...rest, ...inp}
  } else {
    op[name] = {...op[name], ...inp}
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with [`_.flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) that uses [`_.overArgs()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#overArgs) to convert each array to object with it's respective identifier (`_id` or `name`) as key (with [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#keyBy)), and [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) them to a single object. Convert the object back to array, by [mapping](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) it while [omitting](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#omit) the `_id` field:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, overArgs, merge, keyBy, map, omit } = _

const combineArrays = flow(
  overArgs((...objs) => merge({}, ...objs), [
    arr1 => keyBy(arr1, '_id'),
    arr2 => keyBy(arr2, 'name')    
  ]),
  pr(map, o => omit(o, '_id'))
)

const arr1 = [{"_id": "electronics", "number": 35 }, {"_id": "house Appliances", "number": 5 }]
const arr2 = [{"name": "electronics", "purpose": "entertainment", "price": 100},{"name": "house Appliances", "purpose": "general", "price": 200},{"name": "watches", "purpose": "time", "price": 30}]
 
const combinedArrs = combineArrays(arr1, arr2)

console.log(combinedArrs)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And a terser version using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
const { flow, overArgs, merge, keyBy, map, omit } = _

const combineArrays = flow(
  overArgs(merge, [keyBy('_id'), keyBy('name')]),
  map(omit('_id'))
)

const arr1 = [{"_id": "electronics", "number": 35 }, {"_id": "house Appliances", "number": 5 }]
const arr2 = [{"name": "electronics", "purpose": "entertainment", "price": 100},{"name": "house Appliances", "purpose": "general", "price": 200},{"name": "watches", "purpose": "time", "price": 30}]
 
const combinedArrs = combineArrays(arr1, arr2)

console.log(combinedArrs)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

With vanilla JS, you can [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the arrays, and then use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert the arrays to object using the `_id` or `name` as key, and combining items with the same key with [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals). Then convert back to array with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const combineArrays = (arr1, arr2) => Object.values(
  arr1.concat(arr2) // combine the arrays
    .reduce((r, { _id, ...o }) => { // clone the object and remove _id if exists
      const key = _id || o.name // the key is the _id or the name if _id doesn't exist

      r[key] = r[key] ? { ...r[key], ...o } : o // if the key exists on the accumulator combine with current item, if not set current item to the key

      return r;
    }, {})
)

const arr1 = [{"_id": "electronics", "number": 35 }, {"_id": "house Appliances", "number": 5 }]
const arr2 = [{"name": "electronics", "purpose": "entertainment", "price": 100},{"name": "house Appliances", "purpose": "general", "price": 200},{"name": "watches", "purpose": "time", "price": 30}]
 
const combinedArrs = combineArrays(arr1, arr2)

console.log(combinedArrs)
```